# Do new features, updates, design use feat: in semantic commit message convention?

Tags: commit, conventional-commits

I've decided to use semantic commit messages in my new toy project. 
I saw kinds of types of semantic commit messages.

| type | description |
| --- | --- |
| feat | new feature for the user, not a new feature for build script |
| fix | bug fix for the user, not a fix to a build script |
| docs | changes to the documentation |
| style | formatting, missing semi colons, etc; no production code change |
| refactor | refactoring production code, eg. renaming a variable |
| test | adding missing tests, refactoring tests; no production code change |
| chore | updating grunt tasks etc; no production code change |

For frontend engineers
design, updates and new features, all of them use a semantic `feat:`?
Isn't there a semantic like `design:` or `update:`?

Comment: Can you give an example of a "design" or "update" which doesn't fit into the other categories?

Answer (score 9):

Following [angulars contribution guidelines](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/22b96b9/CONTRIBUTING.md#type) the `style` wouldn't be the right choice for design (html, css, etc.) changes here.

A few examples for frontend changes:

| what you changed | commit type |
| --- | --- |
| you added html/css for a page footer | feat |
| you fixed a css glitch in IE6 (lol) | fix |
| you added a link to the footer | feat |
| you linted your css and fixed indentation issues and missing semicolons | style |
| you optimized css animations for higher framerates | perf |
| you added a print style | feat |
| you ported existing css and chose to use SASS from now on | refactor |

Answer (score 2):

Let's have a look at [the motivation for semantic commit messages](https://sparkbox.com/foundry/semantic_commit_messages).

> You’ll never again be tempted to include a bug fix and a feature in the same commit. My git log is now an easy-to-skim changelog.

1. Commits do one thing.
2. `git log` is easy to skim.

If you think some new tags would encourage small commits and readable logs for your particular project, add them. But first, consider if you need to.

`update` seems pretty ambiguous. Isn't everything an update? What are you updating and why? If it's to fix a bug, that's a `fix`. If it's to add a feature, that's a `feat`. If it's updating dependencies, that's a `chore`.

`design`... if this is a style change to images, fonts, CSS, etc... that could be `style`. Or it might be distinct and common enough to warrant a new tag. Perhaps `assets` for commits which only touch assets?

Comment: @seongkukhan If you're changing the code style of the HTML and CSS it's style. If you're changing the style of the design, square icons to round icons for example is that a feature? Is there a frontend asset change that isn't a feature?  Concrete examples would help! The important thing is ***the tags have meaning for your project***. They keep your commits focused, and the log easy to skim. If the existing tags don't make sense for front-end work, use what does. I'm not a front-end person, I can't say what tags to use, but `design` and `update` seem broad and ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) You helped a lot. I think 'style' is one of good choice.

Comment: What do you say would be the commit type for a change that just changes the amount of data imported into the db. For example removing a WHERE from a query? The reason for the change was missing data led to errors in frontend. The code for the migration service in backend runs fine though.

Comment: @aProgger There was an error, you fixed it. [It would result in a +0.0.1 change to the version number](https://semver.org/). It's a fix.

Comment: Analogy to semver. Never looked at it like that. I love it :)